# Choose Database for multi-user applications with only a file server (windows)

Tags: sql, database, multi-user, fileserver

I need to choose a database solution for multiple simultaneous users of windows based applications using the same database on a file server.

I need a database that can live on a Window OS file server.

1. Must be shared by several applications running on individual MS
   Windows machines (mostly Windows 7)
2. Made available by file server.
3. Cannot use a database server/engine (due to internal political rules) or
   webpage server.
4. Prefer using C# for a set of WPF applications.
5. Currently using set of VB applications with a set of MS Access
   files - one of these applications has problems and needs a re-write.
6. Current set of about a half-dozen *.mdb files (some with link
   tables) are about 400 MB. Growth at a guess of 10 to 20 MB/year.
7. Up to about a dozen concurrent users each on their own PC
   currently. Don't expect much change on this in the future.
8. All apps both read and write data to the database.
9. Currently several (about 4 people) write ad hoc queries in Access -
   they will continue to need to be able to write queries somehow.
10. Would like to prevent changes in database structure (adding
    tables/columns) by end users.
11. Free software.

The choices I know about are:

1. Access .mdb files (the current situation).
2. SQLite.
3. SQL Server CE.

Are there other systems that might work that fit many or all of the desired characteristics? Are there particular "gotchas" I should know about for the systems that I am considering?

Comment: You will also want to pay attention how concurrent database accesses are handled and how (much of) the database is locked when one user is using a dataset (only the dataset, the whole database, nothing?). Otherwise you might have your database corrupted or data overwritten.

Comment: You should add MySQL, Postgres, SQL Anywhere, and Oracle's individual version to your list.

Comment: Does anyone know which of these works best on a file server with multiple users each on their own PC? - Fran Strayhorn

Answer (score 1):

Well, "Cannot use a database server/engine" makes things harder. So does "free".

I think Access is the only thing in your list that comes close to fulfilling all the requirements. It's not free, but it seems you already have it, so at least it doesn't cost extra.

Access is essentially three different, bundled products.

- Jet database engine
- RAD environment for queries, forms, and reports
- VBA programming environment

If you're using only the database engine, it makes sense to do some testing with SQL Server CE.

Switching to SQLite would probably require additional checks in application code. SQLite supports [storage classes](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), not data types. What does that mean? It means SQLite allows this.

```
sqlite> create table foo (n integer);
sqlite> insert into foo values ('wibble');
sqlite> select n from foo;
wibble
```

[HyperSQL](http://hsqldb.org/) is another possibility. Supports only JDBC, *might* run without a server component.  (Docs weren't immediately clear about that.) I think it would require a lot more work to switch to this than to SQL Server CE.

See also [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) and [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/features/).

Comment: Yes we already have MS Access. We also have Sql Sever Visual Studio 2010. I prefer C# to VB.

Comment: The Microsoft Access 2010 runtime is free: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10910

Comment: @Remou: Thanks, I didn't know the runtime was free. I think the OP would have to find a separate solution for ad hoc queries if they use the Access runtime.

Comment: We currently run Access queries in Access and VB or C# to for applications.